# ChartJS in React throws 'too may re-renders'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to create bar chart using the ChartJS. When I start my app, there is nothing on web-page, and some errors in console: 'Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

my code:

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from 'chart.js'
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

function App() {

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    datasets:[],
  })

  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
    setChartData({
      labels: ['john','kevin','george','mike','oreo'],
      datasets:[
        {
          label: 'label',
          data: [12,55,34,120,720],
          borderColor: 'green',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
      ],
    })
  },[])
  setChartOptions({
    responsive:true,
    plugins:{
      legend:{
        position:'top'
      },
      title:{
        display:true,
        text:'text from tittle'
      }
    }
  })


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Bar options={chartOptions} data={chartData}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

what should I do to see chart on my web-page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dependency array to `useEffect`. Excluding items from the dependency array may lead to an infinite chain of updates.

Add the dependency array as the second parameter of `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    setChartData({
      labels: ['john','kevin','george','mike','oreo'],
      datasets:[
        {
          label: 'label',
          data: [12,55,34,120,720],
          borderColor: 'green',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
      ],
    })
  },[])
  setChartOptions({
    responsive:true,
    plugins:{
      legend:{
        position:'top'
      },
      title:{
        display:true,
        text:'text from tittle'
      }
    }
  }, [chartOptions, chartData]) // effect will run when either changes
```

Want to run the effect only once?

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

Find out more in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)